# Observable Collection Edit items if exists else add new one

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have some textbox in my window, their content will be added into Observable Collection after clicking on btn_add then will be a source for dg_VoucherDetail.
Problem is :
When I use it first time everything is fine but second time it just replace the old Observable Collection except adding new item to old Collection,
and for edit section there is no item in Collection to search and edit.
Here is The Code :

```
    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _VoucherDetail = new ObservableCollection<VoucherDetail>();
        VoucherDetail Voucher = new VoucherDetail();

        if (dg_VoucherDetail.HasItems == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _VoucherDetail.Count; i++)
            {
                if (_VoucherDetail[i].LedgerID == SelectedLedgerID)
                {
                    if (_VoucherDetail[i].DefinitiveID == SelectedDefinitiveID)
                    {
                        if (_VoucherDetail[i].Credit == Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text))
                            return;
                        else if (_VoucherDetail[i].Debit == Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text))
                            return;
                        else
                        {
                            Voucher.LedgerID = SelectedLedgerID;
                            Voucher.DefinitiveID = SelectedDefinitiveID;
                            if (radio_debit.IsChecked == true)
                            {
                                Voucher.Debit = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text);
                                Voucher.Credit = 0;
                            }
                            else if (radio_credit.IsChecked == true)
                            {
                                Voucher.Debit = 0;
                                Voucher.Credit = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text);
                            }
                            _VoucherDetail[i] = Voucher;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (_VoucherDetail[i].DefinitiveID != SelectedDefinitiveID)
                    {
                        Voucher.LedgerID = SelectedLedgerID;
                        Voucher.DefinitiveID = SelectedDefinitiveID;
                        if (radio_debit.IsChecked == true)
                        {
                            Voucher.Debit = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text);
                            Voucher.Credit = 0;
                        }
                        else if (radio_credit.IsChecked == true)
                        {
                            Voucher.Debit = 0;
                            Voucher.Credit = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text);
                        }
                        _VoucherDetail.Add(Voucher);
                    }
                }
                else if (_VoucherDetail[i].LedgerID != SelectedLedgerID)
                {
                    Voucher.LedgerID = SelectedLedgerID;
                    Voucher.DefinitiveID = SelectedDefinitiveID;
                    if (radio_debit.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        Voucher.Debit = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text);
                        Voucher.Credit = 0;
                    }
                    else if (radio_credit.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        Voucher.Debit = 0;
                        Voucher.Credit = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text);
                    }
                    _VoucherDetail.Add(Voucher);
                }
            }
        }
        if (dg_VoucherDetail.HasItems == false)
        {
            Voucher.LedgerID = SelectedLedgerID;
            Voucher.DefinitiveID = SelectedDefinitiveID;
            if (radio_debit.IsChecked == true)
            {
                Voucher.Debit = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text);
                Voucher.Credit = 0;
            }
            else if (radio_credit.IsChecked == true)
            {
                Voucher.Debit = 0;
                Voucher.Credit = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Amount.Text);
            }
            _VoucherDetail.Add(Voucher);
  //          dg_VoucherDetail.Items.Add(VoucherDetail);
        }
        dg_VoucherDetail.ItemsSource = _VoucherDetail;
    }


    internal class VoucherDetail
{
    public decimal LedgerID { get; set; }
    public decimal DefinitiveID { get; set; }
    public decimal Debit { get; set; }
    public decimal Credit { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple snippet which "updates" an entry if the entry is present in the collection. This snippet has things hard-coded but making it dynamic should be trivial.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace UpdateObservableCollection_47291451
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
        Button btn = new Button();
        ObservableCollection<VoucherDetail> datasource = new ObservableCollection<VoucherDetail>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dg.Height = 200;
            dg.Width = 500;
            MainGrid.Children.Add(dg);//add DataGrid to page
            btn.Content = "Click me";
            btn.Click += Btn_Click;
            btn.Height = 25;
            btn.Width = 50;
            MainGrid.Children.Add(btn);//add button to page

            dg.ItemsSource = datasource;//bind grid to data

            //create initial data records
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                datasource.Add(new UpdateObservableCollection_47291451.VoucherDetail { Credit = i, Debit = i, DefinitiveID = i, LedgerID = i });
            }
        }

        private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if a record with DefinitiveID of 1 exist, then update the entry
            if (datasource.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DefinitiveID == 1) != null)
            {
                datasource.First(p => p.DefinitiveID == 1).Credit = 1234;
                dg.Items.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                datasource.Add(new UpdateObservableCollection_47291451.VoucherDetail { DefinitiveID = 99, Credit = 99, Debit = 99, LedgerID = 99 });
            }
        }
    }


    internal class VoucherDetail
    {
        public decimal LedgerID { get; set; }
        public decimal DefinitiveID { get; set; }
        public decimal Debit { get; set; }
        public decimal Credit { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: thank you @blaze_125 the most useful help i have seen in 2 weeks, works great